# Access to model instance up the where chain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to, within the record found through an association, retain access to the related model instance which found it?

Example:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
  attr_accessor :info_of_the_moment
end

p = Person.first
p.info_of_the_moment = "I don't want this in the db"
assignment = p.assignments.first
assignment.somehow_get_p.info_of_the_moment # or some such magic!
```

And/or is there a way to "hang on to" the parameters of a scope and have access to them from within the found model instance? Like:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
  attr_accessor :info_of_the_moment
  scope :fun_assignments, -> (info) { where(fun: true) }
end

class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person

  def get_original_info
    # When I was found, info was passed into the scope. What was it?
  end
end
```

Comment: Since an assignment belongs to `Person`, then `assignment.somehow_get_p.info_of_the_moment` would be `assignment.person.info_of_the_moment` wouldn't it?

Comment: @lurker but that would not be the original instance so `info_of_the_moment` will not be set.

Comment: It's hard to tell from this example when `info_of_the_moment` may have been set for the first assignment found for `p`. Seems like you have a broader problem you're trying to solve using this mechanism and maybe there's a better mechanism for solving the original problem.

Comment: Guilty as charged! Since asking this question I have started to rethink my entire situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own extension methods to an association and those methods can get at the association's owner through `proxy_association`:

```
has_many :things do
  def m
    # Look at proxy_association.owner in here
  end
end
```

So you could say things like:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments do
    def with_info
      info = proxy_association.owner.info_of_the_moment
      # Then we wave our hands and some magic happens to encode
      # `info` into a properly escaped SQL literal that we can
      # toss in a `select` call. If you're working with PostgreSQL
      # then JSON would be a reasonable first choice if the info
      # was, say, a hash.
      #
      # The `::jsonb` in the `select` call is there to tell everyone
      # that the `info_of_the_moment` column is JSON and should be
      # decoded as such by ActiveRecord.
      encoded_info = ApplicationRecord.connection.quote(info.to_json)
      select("assignments.*, #{encoded_info}::jsonb as info_of_the_moment")
    end
  end
  #...
end

p = Person.first
p.info_of_the_moment = { 'some hash' => 'that does', 'not go in' => 'the database' }
assignment = p.assignments.with_info.first
assignment.info_of_the_moment # And out comes the hash but with stringified keys regardless of the original format.

# These will also include the `info_of_the_moment`
p.assignments.where(...).with_info
p.assignments.with_info.where(...)
```

Things of note:

- All the columns in `select` show up as methods even when they're not part of the table in question.
- You can add "extension" methods to an association by including a block with those methods when calling the association's method.
- An SQL SELECT can include values that aren't columns, literals work just fine.
- What format you use to tunnel your extra information through the association depends on the underlying database.
- If the encoded extra information is large then this can get expensive.

This is admittedly a bit kludgey and brittle so I'd agree with you that rethinking your whole approach is a better idea.